# HTTP to HTTPS using mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for a simple way to have this done. I would to have the .htaccess file rewrite to HTTPS if this is typed in the address bar:

- *www.example.com*
- *example.com*
- *http://www.example.com*

I would like any of these potabilities redirect to *https://www.example.com*

Thanks guys... I haven't found anything for this situation.

Just wanted to say that the answer below did not work for me... is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to check the port the request is coming in on.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Well I want it to point any entered combination to resolve to https://www.mydomain.org. The above option allowed me to enter mydomain.org and that would resolve to http://mydomain.org.

Thanks for the response Laurence