# mod-rewrite to re-direct to https and a /secure/ folder?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was wondering if there is anyway to do a mod-rewrite so if the user types `http://www.url.co.uk`, it will automatically re-direct them to `https://www.url.co.uk/secure/folder/`

? If not, I can move everything into the root, and then do a PHP re-direct if there's no https, but that's not ideal for this case...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it can be done using mod_rewrite. Place this code in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/secure/folder/ [L,R]
```

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest changing `R` to `R=301` once you verify it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

That was answered here:
[HTTP to HTTPS using mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322787/http-to-https-using-mod-rewrite)
You can easily add your custom folder in the statement on the third line.